# how to set array in URL query param

Tags: javascript, query-string

I have multi-checkbox inputs. if checked, I want set query params like this:

topic[]=1&topic[]=2&...

please help me resolve this problem

this is my code for unique param:

```
const addQueryParam = (name, value) => {
  const urlParam = new URL(window.location.href);
  if (!value) {
    urlParam.searchParams.delete(name);
  } else {
    urlParam.searchParams.set(name, value);
  }
  window.history.pushState({ path: urlParam.href }, "", urlParam.href);
};
```

Comment: Welcome, if you're trying to do this with Javascript please post the code that you've tried. Stack Overflow works best with questions where you've tried something and gotten an error or it just doesn't work. If you're looking for guidance on where to start you might get better luck posting on a Javascript beginner's user forum.

Answer (score 0):

You can build the query params with something like this:

```
// Values I want to pass by queryParams
const params = { name: 'Jhons', multiCheckbox: [1, 2, 3], ...otherValues};
```

Then I go through the object to build the string that I will pass to the query params

```
let queryParams = ''; 
Object.keys(params).map(key => {
  if (Array.isArray(params[key])) {
    queryParams += params[key].map((value) => `${key}[]=${value}`).join('&')
  }
  queryParams += `${key}=${params[key]}&`
})
```

Print the `queryParams` to get something like this:

```
'name=Jhons&multiCheckbox[]=1&multiCheckbox[]=2&multiCheckbox[]=3'
```